# Javascript working, but not in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following piece of javascript code, which executes perfectly on a normal html page:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#object{{ object.position }} img:eq(0)')[0].style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');
        setInterval(function(){
        $('#object{{ object.position }} img:eq(0)').fadeOut({{ object.data()['fadeSpeed'] }}, function() {
            this.style.setProperty('display', 'none', 'important');
        })
            .next('img').fadeIn({{ object.data()['fadeSpeed'] }}, function() {this.style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');})
            .end().appendTo('#object{{ object.id }}');},
            {{ object.data()['durationInSeconds'] * 1000 }});
});
```

It fetches a div, checks all img tags and rotates between them(basically a slideshow).

I am learning about Vue components and moved it to one. It looks like this:

```
methods: {
    imageSlideShow: function() {
      var fadeSpeed = this.data.fadeSpeed;
      $(function() {
        $("#object" + this.position + " img:eq(0)")
          .fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
            this.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
          })
          .next("img")
          .fadeIn(fadeSpeed, function() {
            this.style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");
          })
          .end()
          .appendTo("#object" + this.position);
      }, this.data.durationInSeconds * 1000);
    },
  }
```

This failes because of

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Can someone explain to me why this.style is no longer referencing to the div (as it was during the javascript)?

Comment: try use arrow function to keep lexical `this` so it will have the same value as it did right before the arrow function was assigned `fadeOut(fadeSpeed, () => {
            this.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
          })`

Comment: Have you tried to debug what the context of `this` is bound to, logging it to see what its contents is might give you a quicker indication of what's wrong than only reading the code on its own and not know what's actually happening at runtime.